# Pgfplots working as standalone but not in main document

Tags: pgfplotstable, standalone

**Update 1**
The data file can be downloaded here> [11855-4_RT.dat](http://www.benbehr.eu/stackexchange/posts174803/11855-4_RT.dat)

**Original:**
In my main document I have been including a `pgfplotstable` as:

```
\SSTeTableTypeT %contains \pgfplotstableset - included in the end of the question.
\pgfplotstabletypeset[ %
    every head row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{SSTe results based on input data from ISO 11855-4} %
    \label{tab:SSTe11855-4_TypeT}\\ %
    \toprule},}
]{DataSSTe/11855-4_RT.dat}
```

This used to work until I made some changes to the program that is generating the data I want to put in a table. In an attempt to find the problem I used the `standalone` package and created the following (I have not included all that is needed to typeset this - if it helps I can provide a link to all the data for download):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

% Usepackages
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Needed for Definitions
\input{../Setup/Definitions} % Global definitions of units I use throughout the document

% Setting the table environment
\input{../Setup/pgfplots} % defining \SSTeTableTypeT (included below)

% Data Source Folder
\newcommand{\SSTeData}{../DataSSTe/} % the content of the table
                                     % this is included as the relative 
                                     % path changes when included in the main document

\begin{document}
\SSTeTableTypeT % see below for details
\pgfplotstabletypeset[ %
    every head row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{SSTe results based on input data from ISO 11855-4} %
    \label{tab:SSTe11855-4_TypeT}\\ %
    \toprule},}
]{\SSTeData/11855-4_RT.dat}
\end{document}
```

If I just typeset the above a `standalone` I will get a table that is just as I would like to have it. However, if I include it into my main document as:

```
\usepackage[mode=build]{standalone} % image or build or ...
...
\includestandalone{Table/SSTe11855-4_RT}
```

I get the error: *Missing \endgroup inserted ]{\SSTeData/11855-4_RT.dat}*

If I just write

```
\input{Table/SSTe11855-4_RT}
```

the code will, however, compile without any problems.

Why is the `\endgroup` missing the one way but all is fine the other way around?

Honestly, I don't have an idea what the problem really is and, therefore, also have not been able to search for a solution myself. I just don't know where to look. Even though it works using `\input` I would prefer to use `\includestandalone` as it speeds up the build process as long as I just use the image option.

---

How the table looks if set in standalone

### [image]

Definition of \SSTeTableTypeT that is stored in ../setup/pgfplots

```
\newcommand{\SSTeTableTypeT}{\pgfplotstableset{%
reset styles,
disable rowcol styles=false,
%   comment chars={0},
columns={time, 
                tHWaterIn,
                tHSetWaterIn,
                tHWaterOut,
                tHF,
                tHP,
                tHC,
                tHIws,
                tHIw,
                tHA,
                tHMr,
                tHOp},
                columns/time/.style={
                    column name={Step},
                    fixed,
                },
                columns/tHWaterIn/.style={
                    column name={$\tHWaterIn$},
                    fixed zerofill, 
                    precision=1,
                    fixed,
                },
                columns/tHSetWaterIn/.style={
                    column name={$\tHSetWaterIn$},
                    fixed zerofill, 
                    precision=1,
                    fixed,
                },
                columns/tHWaterOut/.style={
                    column name={$\tHWaterOut$},
                    fixed zerofill, 
                    precision=1,
                    fixed,
                },
                columns/tHF/.style={
                    column name={$\tHF$},
                    fixed zerofill, 
                    precision=1,
                    fixed,
                },
                columns/tHP/.style={
                    column name={$\tHP$},
                    fixed zerofill, 
                    precision=1,
                    fixed,
                },
                columns/tHC/.style={
                    column name={$\tHC$},
                    fixed zerofill, 
                    precision=1,
                    fixed,
                },
                columns/tHIws/.style={
                    column name={$\tHIws$},
                    fixed zerofill, 
                    precision=1,
                    fixed,
                },
                columns/tHIw/.style={
                    column name={$\tHIw$},
                    fixed zerofill, 
                    precision=1,
                    fixed,
                },
                columns/tHA/.style={
                    column name={$\tHA$},
                    fixed zerofill, 
                    precision=1,
                    fixed,
                },
                columns/tHMr/.style={
                    column name={$\tHMr$},
                    fixed zerofill, 
                    precision=1,
                    fixed,
                },
                columns/tHOp/.style={
                    column name={$\tHOp$},
                    fixed zerofill, 
                    precision=1,
                    fixed,
                },
%   row sep=\\,
begin table=\begin{longtable},
every first row/.append style={ %
            before row={\midrule
        \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{12}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
            \midrule
        \endhead
            \bottomrule
        \endfoot
            \bottomrule
            \endlastfoot
        }, 
    },
    end table=\end{longtable},
}
}
```

Comment: You have a backslash in `{\SSTeData/11855-4_RT.dat}`?

Comment: @percusse Yes, thats because `\SSTeData` is used to set the document location. Basically the data I use is in a different relative location depending if is set the document with standalone or as part of the main document.
For standalone it is: `../DataSSTe/` 
and if used in the main document it is only: `DataSSTe/`

Comment: I have been using the same system for the source file location with tikz-pictures and never had a problem with that.

Comment: Can you put the first 5-6 rows of data in the question too?

Comment: @percusse I could not post it into the listing itself. That somehow messed it up. But I have added a linke to the file at the top. It is a plain text file.